# how to bold text of calculated member row in crosstab crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports

In crosstab report of crystal report, I have

```
A   aa      1
    bb      2
    cc      0
    dd      1
   ATotal   4

B   tt      0
    yy      1
    hh      0
    jj      1
   BTotal   2
```

Here **ATotal** and **BTotal** are derived from the calculated member...
These are displaying as regular font as of aa,bb,cc....I want to have these ATotal and BTotal only  as **Bold** letter, rest aa,bb,cc as regular.

Can anyone plz help me out from this?

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the cross-tab in design and in preview modes.  Also, which version of CR are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the desired field and type CTRL+B.

Comment: Calculated members are not displayed in the cross tab box in design view.

Comment: Thanks craig for your reply...
I was not thinking that it will work, but it worked.

Simply I pressed  CTRL+B on column grouping field in design page, than only calculated members become bold rest as regular...why I dont know...but it worked for me....thanks

Can you please tell me how to bold those correspoding row values in that coming from the summarized formula in calculated member...

Like here...ATotal   4 both values as bold.